# C++ collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I tried to make a program to insert a data into an array and I wanted to do it using pointers so that I can create a new array and make use of pointers to point to it simply. But I got a error and other SO questions didn't helped.
CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool insert(int arr[], int size, int elem, int pos);

int main()
{
    // Create a array
    int arrayData[] = {0, 3, 4, 3};
    int *arrptr = arrayData;

    int size = sizeof(arrayData) / sizeof(*arrayData);

    int elem = 6, pos = 3;

    // insert the element to position pos
    insert(arrptr, size, elem, pos);

    return 0;
}

bool insert(int *arr[], int size, int elem, int pos)
{
    int newArray[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i < pos)
        {
            newArray[i] = *arr[i];
        }
        else if (i == pos)
        {
            newArray[i] = elem;
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[i] = *arr[i - 1];
        }
    }
    *arr = newArray;
    return true;
}
```

ERROR:

```
/tmp/ccwuU0I9.o: In function `main':
arrayInsertion.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `insert(int*, int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Compare the types of the arguments of your implementation of `insert` with the error message.

Comment: Then your logic in the `insert` function will never work. First of all C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so `newArray` is invalid. Secondly you declare `arr` to be an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. Thirdly, arrays will have a fixed size that you can't change. The natural solution for "dynamic arrays" in C++ is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2):

These two declarations

```
bool insert(int arr[], int size, int elem, int pos);
            ^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
bool insert(int *arr[], int size, int elem, int pos)
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

differ.

Also variable length arrays

```
int newArray[size + 1];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

And this statement

```
*arr = newArray;
```

does not make sense because the variable arr is a local variable of the function. Its changing does not have effect on the passed argument.

You have initially to allocate the source array dynamically.

And the array will be enlarged without adding new values if the given position is greater than the current size of the initial array.